# Checkbox does not hold checked status after disabling the checkbox

Tags: html

I have form with checkbox used in both add/edit mode but have scenario when in edit mode disable the checkbox with its value like checked or unchecked.

I have tried as below but not succeeded,

```
<input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" checked="checked">
```

Comment: Works just fine in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/ugwoLz6b/

Comment: works fine firefox also http://jsfiddle.net/Lqv56ef2/

Answer (score 0):

If an element is disabled, it's value is not posted along with the form, so while the checkbox appears checked, that information is not in the form data.

You may want to store the value in a hidden element, or (better, I think), let the server side script determine the proper default value if it is omitted.